# Chrome redirect to login while Safari works properly

Tags: laravel, google-chrome

A simple project management tool, created with Laravel, works properly till yesterday. When I will create a new todo, in Safari it works well. In Chrome, the application redirect to the login page.

I have no idea where I have to start searching.

Comment: `php artisan optimize:clear` - clear your cache files and check , share your redirect codes ??

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue. I believe it's happening due to latest MS security patches. You probably want to try looking up whats been installed

That's assuming you host it on windows

Comment: No it's on a linux server

Comment: I found out, that it's linked to the numbers of rows in the db. on the project index, i show all the rows. unfortunately, there are a lot of loops so that more than 1000 queries where executed. Then, when i click on create todo, the app redirect to the login page. 
is there a limit of cache which can set higher ?